# Ext in symmetric algebras and group algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, finite-groups

Let $A$ be a selfinjective algebra and for an indecomposable module $M$ define $\psi_M:= \inf \{ i \geq 1 | Ext_A^i(M,M) \neq 0 \}$.

Questions:

1. In case $A$ is symmetric, do we have $\psi_M \leq max \{ \psi_S | S $ is simple $\}$ for each indecomposable non-projective module $M$?
   This should be true in case $A$ is representation-finite.
2. In case $A=kG$ is a group algebra over a field of characteristic $p$. Do we have even $\psi_M \leq \psi_K$ when $K$ is the trivial module and each indecomposable non-projective $M$ ? I can prove this for $p$-groups and in case $p$ does not divide the dimension of $M$.

Comment: Why *should* it be true?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez well it seems to be true in the local and the representation-finite case, so I think it is worth asking.

Comment: I am asking why it *should* be true. Explain why it should, as that can only improve your question — claims that something should or should not be unaccompanied with reasons are extremely vaporous in almost all contexts1. Also: it *seems* to be true in those cases or *is* it true?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez 2. Is true for representation-finite and local group algebra. For 1. it is open whether it is true for local algebras. For me having some evidence for large classes of algebras is often enough to pose a question, together with the motivation that a postive answer would have some nice applications. I do not know what you expect as a good answer for why it should be true.

Comment: What I am unsuccessfully trying to tell you is to add that information to the body of your question. Instead of saying that something *should* be true or that it *seems* to be true, say why you think it is true, or why you expect it to be true, by mentioning the evidence you have and so on. Nothing *has* to be true. Newcomers to the subject, specially,  will appreciate that — deontological claims only contribute to make them excluded of some inaccesible lore that would allow them to know, like you do, why things should be true.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Ok, but I just asked 2 questions and so I did not necessarily expect it to be true in this case (when I expect it to be true in a strong sense, I formulate it as a conjecture as in other threads of mine (for example https://mathoverflow.net/questions/289656/question-on-n-torsionless-modules )). Also I have examples of classes of algebras where it is true to give some evidence in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this example answers both questions.

Let $k$ have characteristic $3$, and let $G=C_3\times S_3$.

Then $kG$ has two simple modules, both one-dimensional, and for each simple module $S$, $\text{Ext}^1(S,S)$ is one-dimensional.

But if $M=kC_3$, with $S_3$ acting trivially, then $\text{Ext}^i(M,M)=0$ for $i=1,2$.

Comment: thanks, how to see that $Ext^i(M,M)=0$ for $i=1,2$ quickly? The quiver of $KG$ should have loops at both points so this shows that $Ext^1(S,S)$ should be nonzero for the simples.

Comment: @Mare A projective resolution for $M$ can be obtained by tensoring $M$, considered as a $kC_3$-module, with a projective $kS_3$-resolution of the trivial module, and then the calculation follows easily.

Comment: @Mare A more general example would be to take two algebras (over an algebraically closed field, say, to avoid non-separability issues): $B$ a non-semisimple local algebra, and $C$ an algebra such that $\text{Ext}^1(S,S)=0$ for every simple $C$-module. Then take $A=B\otimes_kC$ and $M=B\otimes_kS$ for $S$ a simple $C$-module.

Comment: Thanks, that is clever and makes it easy to calculate $Ext$.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $A$ is commutative local (necessarily artinian) with the only simple $k\neq A$  then $\psi_k=1$, so your statement 1 will say that $Ext^1_A(M,M)=0$ implies $M$ is free.  I stated it as a conjecture for complete intersections [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4614-5292-8_10) (conjecture 9.1.3). Technically, it was stated as $Ext^1_A(M,N)=0$ implies $Ext^i_A(M,N)=0$ for all $i>0$, but when $M=N$ the latter condition is equivalent to $M$ being free.

One could also ask if $Ext^1_A(M,M)=0$ implies $M$ is free, still assuming that $A$ is Gorenstein. It was stated as a question (9.1.4) in the same survey.

As far as I know, both are open even for complete intersections unless $A$ is a hypersurface (which will be representation finite anyway).

Comment: Thanks, as far as I know it is in general open whether $Ext_A^1(M,M) \neq 0$ for any non-projective indecomposable module over a finite dimensional local selfinjective algebra. (not necessarily commutative).

Comment: @Mare: isn't Jeremy's answer a counter-example to that statement in non-commutative case?

Comment: No, his example is not local.

Comment: @Mare: interesting. Was that stated somewhere before your question?

Comment: Not that I know of. In general the statement that $Ext^i(M,M) \neq 0$ for some $i >0$ is known as the first Tachikawa conjecture. But in the local case it was never stated as a conjecture that $Ext^1(M,M) \neq 0$ as far as I know. There are some special cases in the literature that suggest that one might state this as a conjecture. For example Hoshino proved it for radical cube zero algebras, Tachikawa proved it for group algebras of $p$-groups (I noted that one can generalise Tachikawa's result to local Hopf algebras).

Comment: The article https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869308002664 claims to prove in the commutative case that $Ext^1(M,M) \neq 0$ or $Ext^2(M,M) \neq 0$ but there are some doubts that the proof is complete.

Comment: @Mare: yes, I saw that there were some issues with that paper, specified here, footnote on page 1: http://s.web.umkc.edu/segal/papers/AR.pdf